# Making related query?

Tags: django

There are 3 models, I want to execute a query like this

> **select article_id from votes_vote where user_id=user.id and value=True**

with the orm. I try this

> Article.objects.filter(author=user.id, likes=True)

**Vote**

```
class Vote(models.Model):
   value = models.NullBooleanField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   article = models.ForeignKey(Article,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='likes')

    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
```

**article**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=400)
    # El campo RichTextUploading lo heredo de CKEDITOR
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**user**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Lista de cohortes de Academlo

    COURSE_START = [
        ('J2019', 'Julio 2019'),
        ('E2020', 'Enero 2020'),
        ('M2020', 'Mayo 2020'),
    ]

    GENDER = [
        ('M', 'Hombre'),
        ('F', 'Mujer')
    ]

    # Campos de usuario
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=300, blank=False)
    course = models.CharField(choices=COURSE_START, max_length=5)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Article.objects.filter(likes__user=user, value=True)
```

Here you need to use `likes` as parameter, as it is defined as *related_name*. By using it, you should be able access votes instances for reverse query.

More information can be found in [documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects).